# PromQL delta for each elment in values array

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am using PromQL to get the values of a counter for the last 5m minutes but I would like to get the counters delta value for each value returned. I can query using `delta(http_requests[5m])` but it only returns the delta of the first and last element. Is there a way to get all values back as delta values? I've looked through the prometheus functions [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/) but cannot find a method to do this.

```
http_requests[5m]

{
    "data": {
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {
                    "__name__": "http_requests",
                    "app": "cloud_engine",
                    "app_instance": "instance_01",
                },
                "values": [
                    [
                        "2021-10-26T02:33:07Z",
                        "36446"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2021-10-26T02:34:07Z",
                        "36447"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2021-10-26T02:35:07Z",
                        "36448"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2021-10-26T02:36:07Z",
                        "36450"
                    ],
                    [
                        "2021-10-26T02:37:07Z",
                        "36450"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        "resultType": "matrix"
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

**Desired result showing deltas for each value:**

```
        "values": [
            [
                "2021-10-26T02:33:07Z",
                "0"
            ],
            [
                "2021-10-26T02:34:07Z",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2021-10-26T02:35:07Z",
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2021-10-26T02:36:07Z",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "2021-10-26T02:37:07Z",
                "0"
            ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the interval between samples (e.g. one minute in the example above), then the following [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) can be used:

```
delta(http_requests[1m])[5m:1m]
```

This instant query should return the last 5 deltas on 1-minute interval. Unfortunately, it is likely Prometheus will return empty results, since it needs at least two samples on the lookbehind window in square brackets for `delta` calculations, e.g. it doesn't take into account the difference between the last point before the lookbehind window and the first point in the lookbehind window. So the query must be rewritten to:

```
delta(http_requests[2m])[5m:1m]
```

Unfortumatele this query may give unexpected results because of the same issue - Prometheus skips the delta between the last sample before the lookbehind window and the first sample in the lookbehind window `[2m]`.

P.S. An alternative solution is to try the first query in VictoriaMetrics. It takes into account the delta mentioned above, so it must return the expected results. See more details at [MetricsQL docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). Take a look also at [rollup_delta](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup_delta) function - it calculates deltas between consecutive samples on the given lookbehind window and then returns `max`, `min` and `avg` values from the calculated deltas.

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use "delta(http_requests[1m])" and you'll get the delta between each element and its predecessor, as desired.

Comment: I tried using the delta function `delta(http_requests[5m])` but I only get the single value from the array returned instead the delta for each element. The series is per minute and I am looking for all values as delta.

Comment: The [5m] means that the delta will be between each element and its 5m predecessor. You will receive this result for ALL elements in the metric.

Comment: Okay got it thanks. I was looking to get a series of data for last X timeframe but get the delta value. For example the last 5 minutes for a counter but have the 5 values as delta values. I'm sorry if my question did not relay that. Is that possible?