# PromQL for each element in module

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a prometheus exporter, which gives the following result:

```
# HELP apartment 
# TYPE apartment gauge
apartment{module="ddcga"} 2.323522e+09
# HELP bar 
# TYPE bar gauge
bar{module="ddcga"} 7.50631e+08
[...]
```

Now i want to see those values in Grafana, but for them to be actually useful, i need to use the `delta` function.

For one value, this is pretty straight forward: `delta(apartment{module="ddcga"}[1h])`

But there actually are a lot of values, and adding / changing them all manually is a lot of work and error prone looking forward.

I can already display every value using just `{module="ddcga"}` but using `delta({module="ddcga"}[1h])` gives the error `execution: vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset`.

How can i make this work?

Additional:

- I am using https://github.com/RichiH/modbus_exporter as prometheus exporter
- Would be extra cool, if i could use `{{__name__}}` as legend
- This is *not* a duplicate of [PromQL delta for each elment in values array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69716931/promql-delta-for-each-elment-in-values-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus drops metric names from the input time series when it applies various functions such as [delta()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta). This results in the `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` error, since multiple input time series will have the same set of `label=value` pairs after metric name removal.

This task can be resolved with a hack on [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) combined with [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function. For example, the following query would calculate the delta over the previous hour per each time series with the `module="ddcgq"` label with a minute precision. The inner `label_replace()` moves the metric name to a `metric_name` label:

```
delta(
  label_replace({module="ddcga"}, "metric_name", "$1", "__name__", "(.+)")[1h:1m]
)
```

P.S. This task is much easier to solve with VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It supports `keep_metric_names` modifier specifically for this case:

```
delta({module="ddcga"}[1h]) keep_metric_names
```

This query returns one-hour deltas per each metric with the label `module="ddcga"`, while keeping the original metric names untouched. See more details in [MetricsQL docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html).